# TABLEAU: How can I measure similarity of sets of dimensions across dates?

Tags: r, data-visualization, tableau-api, level-of-detail

this is a bit of a complicated one - but I'll do my best to explain. I have a dataset comprised of data that I scrape from a particular video on demand interface every day. Each day there are around 120 titles on display (a grid of 12 x 10) - the data includes a range of variables: date of scrape, title of programme, vertical/horizontal position of programme, genre, synopsis, etc.

One of the things I want to do is analyse the similarity of what's on offer on a day-to-day basis. What I mean by this is that I want to compare how many of the titles on a given day appeared on the previous date (ideally expressed as a percentage). So if 40 (out of 120) titles were the same as the previous day, the similarity would be 30%.

Here's the thing - I know how to do this (thanks to some kindly stranger on this very site who helped me write a script using R). You can see the post here which gives some more detail: [Calculate similarity within a dataframe across specific rows (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61526933/calculate-similarity-within-a-dataframe-across-specific-rows-r)

However, this method creates a similarity score based on the total number of titles on a day-to-day basis whereas I also want to be able to explore the similarity after applying other filters. Specifically, I want to narrow the focus to titles that appear within the first four rows and columns. In other words: how many of these titles are the same as the previous day in those positions? I could do this by modifying the R script, but it seems that the better way would be to do this within Tableau so that I can change these parameters in "real-time", so to speak. I.e. if I want to focus on the top 6 rows and columns I don't want to have to run the R script all over again and update the underlying data!

It feels as though I'm missing something very obvious here - maybe it's a simple table calculation? Or I need to somehow tell Tableau how to subset the data?

Hopefully this all makes sense, but I'm happy to clarify if not. Also, I can't provide you the underlying data (for research reasons!) but I can provide a sample if it would help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Both this and another referenced question doesn't have the column depicting position of any title in the grid.  I would like to see your complete data structure in order to suggest any solution/strategy.  Prima facie it appears that you need parameter dependent calculation.  Also please let me know the software u are using to prepare your data.  Tableau desktop/prep etc?

Comment: Please also share a screenshot of table/view you have prepared

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure the best way to share the data with you but have uploaded a sample of it here: http://www.filehost.pt/p3xI. This sample includes three days, but the full dataset has 800+ days. As for the process of preparation: I scrape the data from the iPlayer using Parsehub then clean up/add some data using R. This produces a final dataset which is what I use to build the visualisation in Tableau. :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the data!!! But it is saying that download is not available in my country.  Please share it through google drive/dropbox/onedrive.

Comment: Sorry! Try this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwl2xddnu4wzrvq/iPlayer%20Sample%20Data.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: thanks.  I have downloaded.  So the columns to be used here are title, date and row only?  But how have you done your similarity analysis?  any column generated in R is not shown in your sample data?

Comment: The only variables relevant to this analysis are: title, date. That's what the R script uses to measure how many titles are the same on subsequent days. But I would also like to include row and rank. These refer to the horizontal and vertical position of titles within the interface. E.g. Row 1, rank 1 is the title in the top left hand corner. Row 2, rank 1 is the title directly below that. And yes, the "similarity index" generated with that R script is in a separate dataset (I did this because there is only one value per day but approx 120 entries per day in this dataset). Hope that's clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224890/discussion-between-anilgoyal-and-japes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex has suggested, you can have best of both the worlds.  But to the best of my knowledge, Tableau Desktop allows interface with R (or python etc.) through calculated fields i.e. `script_int` `script_real` etc.  All of these can be used in tableau through *calculated fields*.  Presently these functions in tableau allows creation on calculated field through `Table calculations` which in tableau work only in context.  We cannot hard code these values (fields/columns) and thus. we are not at liberty to use these independent on context.  Moreover, table calculations in tableau can neither be further aggregated and nor be mixed with LOD expressions.  Thus, in your use case, (again to the best of my knowledge) you can build a parameter dependent view in tableau, after hard-coding values through any programming language of your choice.  I therefore, suggest that prior to importing data in tableau a new column can be created in your dataset by running following (or alternate as per choice programming language)

```
movies_edited <- movies %>% group_by(Title) %>%
  mutate(similarity = ifelse(lag(date)== date - lubridate::days(1), 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()

write.csv(movies_edited, "movies_edited.csv")
```

This created a new column named `similarity` in dataset wherein `1` denotes that it was available on previous day, `0` denotes it was not not screened on immediately previous day and `NA` means it is first day of its screening.

I have imported this dataset in tableau and created a parameter dependent view, as you desired.

[image]

Comment: It is simpler to precompute values in R as you show rather than to have Tableau call R interactively — when the use case can be supported by static precomputed values.

Comment: One correction though — you definitely can nest table calculations to perform additional aggregation.

Comment: This is a genius approach - can't believe I'd never thought of it before! I think all three answers offered here would work - but this approach would allow me to play around with the visualisation in real-time because, as you say, the underlying data would be "hard coded" with details of whether a title appeared on the previous day rather than trying to determine this from scratch every time. Thanks again for your advice!

Comment: Glad that it helped.  But there is a downside of this approach, the values will be hard-coded before applying a filter whereas correct approach should be applying filter first and then calculate similarity index.  e.g. if a movie title is repeated across two consecutive days, it will hard code a value 1, but if was screened at different rows/columns on these days then your aggregation may show wrong values.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the best of both worlds. Use Tableau to connect to your data, filter as desired, then have Tableau call an R script to calculate similarity and return the results to Tableau for display.

If this fits your use case, you need to learn the mechanics to put this into play. On the Tableau side, you’ll be using the functions that start with the word SCRIPT to call your R code, for example SCRIPT_REAL(), or SCRIPT_INT() etc. Those are table calculations, so you’ll need to learn how table calculations work, in particular with regard to partitioning and addressing. This is described in the Tableau help. You’ll also have to point Tableau at the host for your R code, by managing external services under the Help->Settings and Performance menu.

On the R side, you’ll have write your function of course, and then use the function RServe() to make it accessible to Tableau. Tableau sends vectors of arguments to R and expects a vector in response. The partitioning and addressing mentioned above controls the size and ordering of those vectors.

It can be a bit tricky to get the mechanics working, but they do work. Practice on something simple first.

See Tableau’s web site resources for more information. The official name for this functionality is Tableau “analytic extensions”

Comment: This is really helpful - thanks. I come from a humanities background so some of this might be beyond my skillset but I'll give it a shot! I had a feeling as though this kind of calculation would have been too complicated to do within Tableau and that it might require some more advanced approach such as this. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 2):

I am sharing a strategy to solve this in R.

**Step-1** Load the libraries and data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

movies <- tibble(read.csv("movies.csv"))
movies$date <- as.Date(movies$date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

set the rows and columns you want to restrict your similarity search to in two variables.  Say you are restricting the search to 5 columns and 4 rows only

```
filter_for_row <- 4
filter_for_col <- 5
```

**Getting final result**

```
movies %>% filter(rank <= filter_for_col, row <= filter_for_row) %>%  #Restricting search to designated rows and columns
  group_by(Title, date) %>% mutate(d_id = row_number()) %>%
  filter(d_id ==1) %>% # removing duplicate titles screened on any given day
  group_by(Title) %>%
  mutate(similarity = ifelse(lag(date)== date - lubridate::days(1), 1, 0)) %>% #checking whether it was screened previous day
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(total_movies_displayed = sum(d_id),
            similar_movies = sum(similarity, na.rm = T), 
            similarity_percent = similar_movies/total_movies_displayed)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  date       total_movies_displayed similar_movies similarity_percent
  <date>                      <int>          <dbl>              <dbl>
1 2018-08-13                     17              0              0    
2 2018-08-14                     17             10              0.588
3 2018-08-15                     17              9              0.529
```

If you change the filters to 12, 12 respectively, then

```
filter_for_row <- 12
filter_for_col <- 12

movies %>% filter(rank <= filter_for_col, row <= filter_for_row) %>%
  group_by(Title, date) %>% mutate(d_id = row_number()) %>%
  filter(d_id ==1) %>%
  group_by(Title) %>%
  mutate(similarity = ifelse(lag(date)== date - lubridate::days(1), 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(total_movies_displayed = sum(d_id),
            similar_movies = sum(similarity, na.rm = T), 
            similarity_percent = similar_movies/total_movies_displayed) 

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  date       total_movies_displayed similar_movies similarity_percent
  <date>                      <int>          <dbl>              <dbl>
1 2018-08-13                     68              0              0    
2 2018-08-14                     75             61              0.813
3 2018-08-15                     72             54              0.75
```

Good Luck